# TypeError: this.$store is undefined in a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I did my research and read a bunch of similar questions there and on a dedicated Vue forum but none of them solve my issue.

I have a component with a login form that triggers a method that dispatches $store action that logs the user in via firebase.

The problem is that i get `[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): "TypeError: this.$store is undefined"` Found in `Login.vue` so i figure $store is unavailable there for some reason.

I made sure that:

- I don't use fat arrow functions in components so that no new context is introduces and 'this' still refers to the Vue instance
- I included `auth.js` store module to the main `store.js` file
- I properly exported store `export default new Vuex.Store({..})` and imported it into `main.js` `import store from './store/store'` and even tried variations of those such as `export ...` without default and `import {store} from './store/store` with curly braces
- Tried renaming main store file from `store.js` into `index.js` and importing the whole folder like `import store from './store'`
- Put async and await where needed
- I do have vuex installed

main.js file

```
import router from './router'
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate'
import { FirebaseApp, initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";
import store from './store'

Vue.use(Vuelidate)

initializeApp({...
})

new Vue({
  store,
  router,
  render: function (h) { return h(App) },
}).$mount('#app')
```

src/store/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import auth from './auth'
Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {

  },
  modules: {
    auth,
  }
})
```

src/store/auth.js

```
import { FirebaseApp } from "firebase/app"

export default {
  actions: {
    async login({dispatch, commit}, {email, password}) {
      try {
        await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      } catch (e) { throw e }
    }
  },
}
```

src/views/empty/Login.vue component

```
<script>
import {email, required, minLength} from 'vuelidate/lib/validators'

export default {
  name: 'login',
  data: () => ({
    email: '',
    password: ''
  }),
  validations: {
    email: {email, required},
    password: {minLength: minLength(8), required}
  },
  methods: {
    async SubmitHandler() {
      if (this.$v.$invalid) {
        this.$v.$touch()
        return
      }
      const formData = {
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password
      }
      try {
        await this.$store.dispatch('login', formData)
      } catch (e) {throw e}
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the same app ? Sometimes the login form is another app that don't use the main.js file

Comment: @Lk77 Yes, all files are from the same project

Comment: Even if it's the same project, it does not means it's the same  vue app, perhaps you have a different app/layout for your login

Comment: @Lk77 Not sure what you mean by this. I only have one Vue instance in my main.js

Comment: I mean by this, that in some projects, the login is a completely separate vue app that don't use the main.js file, try to add a console.log in the main.js file to see if it's actually used. Perhaps your login use vue as a cdn file for example

Comment: @Lk77 So i put console.log(Vue) at the end of main.js and store/index.js files and got two similar outputs in the console: function Vue(options)

Comment: How do you display the Login component ? inside the App component ?

Comment: Why did not you post the Login component, too? What is this async `v-on` handler?

Comment: Make a search on your whole project with the given keywords (`this.$store`). Then narrow down the issue by finding out what part of your codebase is causing the error. If it doesn't work, talk a walk or a shower, you will find it out at some point. Or maybe share a public github repo.

Comment: @IVOGELOV In my `App.vue` i have a router view inside a dynamic component. The dynamic component defines the layout such as 'main-layout' with `MainLayout.vue` responsible for it, 'admin-layout' with `AdminLayout.vue` etc. At this point all of those layout .vue files literally have a single `<router-view>` inside of their templates. `Login.vue` is a view that goes into `EmptyLayout.vue` layout which in turn goes into `App.vue`. 
I don't know how this is related to the question but there you go

Comment: @kissu Maybe i got it wrong but i really don't know how this is going to help me there. I already know that it is `$store` in a `SubmitHandler()` method that is causing the issue. If i replace the whole `SubmitHandler()` with a `console.log('i work')` then it work perfectly fine with no errors

Comment: What if you try to use a mapActions?

Comment: I recommend using your devtools to troubleshoot and inspect what you do have in your `this`by selecting your app and looking for `$vm0` in your console so that you could figure out what is missing.

Comment: @kissu still does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always check versions of the packages you are working with. Remember that `npm install WHATEVER` in most cases defaults to installing the newest version which is not what you want when working with legacy code.

In my case i'm working with Vue 2 so i needed to use Vuex@3 instead of Vuex@4 and firebase-tools 6 or 7

uninstall current firebase tools
`npm uninstall -g firebase-tools`

install legacy firebase (version 7 in this case)
`npm install firebase-tools@7.16.1`

install Vuex version 3 for you Vue 2 application
`npm i vuex@3`